Doubts about the Stable Amplitude of Diodes in Wien Bridge Oscillator
Recently, I have been studying theWien Bridge Oscillator and I am a bit confused about the process of the diode automatically stabilizing its amplitude. The following diagram is used for circuit simulation

The simulation results are shown in the following figure

Due to the fact that the output is a sine signal, under the initial oscillation conditions, the selected signal will be continuously amplified. After amplification to a certain extent, the diode will conduct, and then the feedback resistance will be reduced to decrease the amplification factor. At this time, there will definitely be some amplitudes larger than the diode conduction and some other amplitudes smaller than the diode conduction voltage in one cycle of the signal. If point A in the figure is taken as the critical point, the voltage on the left side of A will increase after multiple rounds of feedback until it equals A. The amplitude on the right side of A will decrease after multiple rounds of feedback until it equals A. This should become a rectangular wave, as shown in the figure below. Please advise.


It should be a sine wave with clipped peaks (there is distortion at the peaks).

Note that you change the "gain" with the 100 Ohm used for the mid-point.

@Antonio51 Thank you for the reminder. I didn't notice it before. I originally just wanted to provide a 6V voltage, but it seems that I need to find another way to provide a 6V voltage

If those diodes were insufficiently forward biased, conducting very little current, then the combined resistance of R4 and R7 would be much closer to R4, as if it were alone:
$$ R_{TOTAL} = R_4 = 21k\Omega $$
When the voltage across the diodes increases, biasing them sufficiently to conduct well, R4 and R7 combined behaviour is more as if they were in parallel:
$$ R_{TOTAL} = R_4 \parallel R_7 = \frac{R_4\times R_7}{R_4+R_7} \approx 10k $$
Here's a simulation showing voltage across the network (blue) for currents between 0 and 50μA, and also voltage across 21kΩ and 10kΩ resistors (orange and brown respectively). I've offset the orange and brown traces vertically, to have them coincide with the blue one:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

What we're really interested in is the slope (gradient) of the graph, \$\frac{dV}{dI}\$, representing resistance.
The network's effective resistance (blue) is a fairly smooth transition from behaving like a 21kΩ resistance, and having behaviour more like a 10kΩ resistance. These two distinct "regimes" fall either side of a "center" voltage of about 0.3V, where it's reasonable to assume that effective resistance will be perhaps 15kΩ.
What is often considered to be a flaw in real-life diodes, their 0.7V "drop" and their sluggish transition between conducting and not-conducting, is actually beneficial in this application. A real-life diode's current vs. voltage curve is smooth, and here it gives rise to a nice smooth transition between the two regimes.
Your description of the scenario paints a much more extreme picture, where combined resistance is very high, or very low, or changes suddenly. In fact, gain (which is directly related to feedback resistance) will only change by a small amount, between the two regimes, and that change will be gradual as input potential rises and falls.
If we consider the feedback network as having resistance \$R_F\$, and that this is a non-inverting amplifier of gain \$1+\frac{R_F}{R_3}\$, then gain \$A\$ at the two extremes will be:
$$ A_{MIN} = 1 + \frac{10k\Omega}{10k\Omega} = 2 $$
$$ A_{MAX} = 1 + \frac{21k\Omega}{10k\Omega} = 3.1 $$
A Wien bridge oscillator's output amplitude is steady (doesn't increase or decrease) when gain is exactly 3, which falls within this range.
Gain changes only by a factor of about \$\frac{3.1}{2}\approx1.5\$ between input large signal amplitudes and small ones. Very small signals (100mV or smaller) will be subject to 1.5 times more gain than larger signals (500mV or more).
Of course, this non-linearity in the relationship between input and output potentials means that the output is not a perfect sinusoid. It is slightly distorted, containing some higher harmonics, but that's easily mitigated by low-pass filtering the output, using an RC filter, Sallen-Key arrangement, or integrator.

Note the change of the "gain" with the 100 Ohm's used for the mid-point.

@Antonio51 I overlooked that. 50Ω, really, from Thevenin. That diminishes gain slightly for sure, but still not under 3.

A lot of good analysis here, but you didn't suggest a change. With the diodes conducting, you want the gain to be slightly less than 3. Try R7 = 100k and see if the sine looks better.

Looking for the clever trick
There is always a clever twist in any famous circuit that we need to identify to fully understand it. In the Wien bridge oscillator, the trick lies in the resistor-capacitor voltage divider connected in the positive feedback loop. Let's see what it is.
The problem
In RC oscillators, under the influence of a "self-reinforcing positive feedback", the voltage across an RC circuit continuously "moves" between the two rails of the supply voltage (changes between its two extreme values). The problem lies in how the voltage reverses its direction of change at the peak points. Let's investigate it by applying a voltage step as an input signal.
Building a Wien bridge circuit
RC integrator circuit
If it were simply an integrating circuit...

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
... the voltage would indeed rise smoothly until it reaches the limiting level, but then it would remain there.

RC differentiator circuit
A dual differentiating circuit...

simulate this circuit
... would produce a sudden change in voltage, or a voltage spike, instead of a gradual increase.

Wien bridge circuit
Obviously, the solution lies in the combination of the two circuits into one. We can assume that Wien's idea was to create a more complex RC voltage divider from the top R1C1 differentiator circuit and the bottom R2C2 integrator circuit.

simulate this circuit
The role of R2 is crucial - when the voltage reaches the upper limit, the capacitor starts to discharge through R2 and the voltage begins to decrease. Without it, the voltage would remain at the limit level.

So, this is the main trick in the Wien bridge circuit - the discharge resistor R2. It is the core of the Wien bridge oscillator and is a perfect example of Don Lancaster's approach of achieving complex results with simple components ("elegant simplicity").
AC exploring a Wien bridge circuit
The oscillation frequency of the OP's circuit is Fosc = 1/2πRC = 1592 Hz.
F < Fosc: If we supply the circuit with a lower frequency (800 Hz)...

simulate this circuit
... the output voltage lags behind the input voltage.

F > Fosc: Conversely, if we supply the circuit with a higher frequency (3 kHz)...

simulate this circuit
... the output voltage leads the input voltage.

F = Fosc: Only when the applied frequency is equal to the oscillator frequency...

simulate this circuit
... there is no phase shift. The output voltage is maximum and equal to 1/3 of the input.

Wien bridge oscillator
With linear NFB network
If we connect a non-inverting amplifier with a gain (slightly greater than) 3 between the output of a Wien bridge oscillator and its input, we obtain an oscillator. Through the positive feedback mechanism, the op-amp output voltage self-increases until it reaches the upper peak. Then it begins to self-decrease until it reaches the lower peak, and so on.
It is intriguing that the oscillator settles on its resonant frequency due to the negative feedback loop.

simulate this circuit
To excite the oscillator we choose a gain slightly greater than three. As a result, the amplitude of the output voltage continuously increases until it approaches the supply voltage and is limited. It can be seen that the distortions are significant.

With non-linear NFB network
The remedy is to limit the gain to 3 before reaching the maximum output voltage. For this purpose, diodes are used to connect resistor R3 in parallel with the existing R5 at the necessary moment, thus smoothly limiting the gain.

simulate this circuit

See also an extensive ResearchGate discussion.
